# Ubuntu screen shows broken pixel (Nvidia driver 18.04)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I can't be 100% sure on how to reproduce the following problem. But it seems like if i play video or start a game for a while, the screen will just freeze and I will have to reboot it. So I can't tell if it is my driver's problem or graphic card's hardware problem or something else.

Here is my setup:

- LG 43 inch screen ([https://www.amazon.com/LG-Electronics-LED-lit-Monitor-43UD79-B/dp/B0711MP768](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0711MP768))

  > ```
  > 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
  > 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
  > 00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 05)
  > 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
  > 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
  > 00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
  > 00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
  > 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
  > 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
  > 00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f0)
  > 00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
  > 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Z270)
  > 00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
  > 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
  > 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
  > 00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-V
  > 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1)
  > 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
  > 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1)
  > 02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
  > 04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
  > 05:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142
  > 06:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142
  > ```

[image]

[image]

```
~  sudo lshw -c display
[sudo] password for yuri: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:139 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:142 memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:dd000000-dd07ffff


~  sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:04:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000014E4d000043A0sv00001043sd000085DFbc02sc80i00
vendor   : Broadcom Limited
model    : BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
driver   : bcmwl-kernel-source - distro non-free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001B80sv00001462sd00003367bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Comment: UPDATE: Took 1 GPU out and it is working fine without crashing (yet). Not sure if it is a power problem or a faulty graphic card.

Comment: Things been working fine now, 1000w maybe not be enough for you to run 2 1080 NVIDIA. You will be able to start up the machine but it will crash when you do "real" work such as start a game or watch video which draw more power!